# Birt: Can we create tree table in birt to represent parent child relationship?

Tags: java, birt

Can we create tree table in birt to represent parent child relationship using birt reporting.

I need something similar to [ExtJS Tree Grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.html)
In my database table childs have a parent id.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, but you could take that example and include it in a BIRT report, loading the node data from data set values using a text element.  It would only work in HTML format though.  The other option is to create a report item extension, that does something like generate an image.